# Formatação de texto em um JTextPane

Tags: java

Olá, tenho um JTextPane e gostaria de formatar partes de seu conteúdo. É possível fazer isto?

```
JTextPane areaDeTexto = new JTextPane();
areaDeTexto.setText = "Este texto está formatado em negrito.\nEste em itálico.\nEste em sublinhado.\nE este não está formatado!";
```

O que faço neste código?

Answer (score 3):

Tente usar o html, colocar os textos nas tags `<b></b>`, `<i></i>` e `<u></u>`, mas lembre de dar setContentType("text/html")
Tente usar o código abaixo

```
public class Formatar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setSize(300, 300);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        JTextPane tp = new JTextPane();
            frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,tp);
            tp.setContentType("text/html");
            tp.setText("<html><b>Texto em Negrito, </b><i>Texto em Itálico, </i><u>Texto Sublinhado</u></html>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A resposta do amigo **Gui_Biem está muito boa!!**
Mas vou deixar a minha também.
 Supondo que ambas as classes estejam no mesmo pacote:

```
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Style;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public class EstiloTextPanel extends JTextPane {

    private Style negrito;
    private Style italico;
    private Style normal;

    public EstiloTextPanel(StyledDocument doc) {
        super(doc);
        initStyles();
    }

    public EstiloTextPanel() {
        super();
        initStyles();
    }

    private void initStyles() {
        normal = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext().getStyle(
                StyleContext.DEFAULT_STYLE);

        negrito = getStyledDocument().addStyle("bold", normal);
        StyleConstants.setBold(negrito, true);

        italico = getStyledDocument().addStyle("italic", normal);
        StyleConstants.setItalic(italico, true);
    }


    public void insertBoldText(String text) throws BadLocationException {
        getStyledDocument().insertString(getStyledDocument().getLength(), text,
                negrito);
    }

    public void insertItalicText(String text) throws BadLocationException {
        getStyledDocument().insertString(getStyledDocument().getLength(), text,
                italico);
    }

    public void insertNormalText(String text) throws BadLocationException {
        getStyledDocument().insertString(getStyledDocument().getLength(), text,
                normal);
    }

}
```

e também:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;

public class TestandoEstiloTextPanel extends JFrame {

    private EstiloTextPanel verPanel;

    public TestandoEstiloTextPanel() throws BadLocationException {
        super("FORMATADO");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300, 300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);


        verPanel = new EstiloTextPanel();
        add(verPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        verPanel.setEditable(false);

        verPanel.insertBoldText("Negrito\n");
        verPanel.insertItalicText("Itálico\n");
        verPanel.insertNormalText("Normal\n");


        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws BadLocationException {
        new TestandoEstiloTextPanel();
    }

}
```